# how to add wrapper div for a image via image formatter in drupal 7?

Tags: hooks

I am creating custom formatter for images using hook_field_formatter_settings_form() in drupal 7.. I need to add wrapper div for my custom formatter. Means when I select this formatter then image should be wrapped by div. 
for example . `<div class="wrap"><img src="#" /></div>`

Answer (score 1):

You need to add one more hook to default add  to field wrapper.

```
 function hook_field_formatter_view($entity_type, $entity, $field, $instance, $langcode, $items, $display) {
  $settings = $display['settings']; // Key needs to be defined in info array (who knew?)
  $element = array();
  if ($display['type'] == 'default_formatter') {
    foreach ($items as $delta => $item) {
      $element = array(
        '#prefix' => '<div class="wrapper">',
        '#suffix' => '</div>',
      );
    }
  }
  return $element;
}
```

Comment: After implement this only wrapper div is showing..Image is not coming under this.

Comment: Its not giving me required input.

Comment: I just add prefix and suffix for this other properties you need add like '#data' => $item ['value']  and setting please refer api.drupal.org for further.

Comment: I used this:foreach ($items as $delta => $item) {
    
      $element [$delta] = array( '#prefix' => '<div class="zoomsnow">','#data' => $item ['value'],  '#suffix' => '</div>', );
    } but still not give me image.